# Is there a way customize priority inbox like this?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, priority-inbox

I would like to customize the priority inbox of my Google Apps email. The top section is already "Important and unread" and the bottom section "Everything else".

In the middle I would like to have the section "In Inbox and having [label]". It seems however that it's only possible to show all message of a certain label.

I also would be satisfied with "Unread in [label]", but also that I can't figure out how to put.

Is what I want possible?

Comment: You MIGHT be able to do something close to that if you use the Multiple Inboxes feature from Labs. I believe the rules for determining which inbox gets what is a little more dynamic, buy you'll lose the automatic prioritization that Priority Inbox offers.

Comment: I used Multiple Inboxes for this. It works so much better than Priority Inbox. I set up three inboxes with is:my-label AND is:inbox, and then an "Other" inbox with -is:my-label-1 AND -is:my-label-2 AND -is:my-label-3 AND is:inbox. The only issue is my cursor keeps focusing down in the (now-irrelevant) combined inbox at the bottom…

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes you can do this but not without a little bit of hacking around.

From my answer at [Equivalent of 'archive' for priority inbox \ multiple inbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/equivalent-of-archive-for-priority-inbox-multiple-inbox) :

The only way that I have found to do it is either with the element inspector in chrome/safari or with firebug in firefox. The good news is that once you have made the settings change it will work in all browsers.

1. Go to the priority inbox settings tab.
2. Click the options next to the section you want to show your work mail.
3. Click "More Options..."
4. Inspect the element for the "Work" Label
5. You will notice on the surrounding div there is an attribute cfg="^all,Work", change the value to "^i,Work"
6. Select the label on the page as you normally would

You will know if it worked or not straight away because the section settings should now read : Inbox, Work instead of the All Work that it used to read.

Here is a list of alternative commands you can use. You can chain commands together with a comma.

```
^i = Inbox
^u = Unread
^io_im = Important
^t = starred
^f = sent
^r = drafts
^all = All mail (include archive)
```

ie. `^i,^u,Work` = all emails in your inbox, that are unread with the label "Work".

Comment: I can only say, WOW. This answer is really good. How did you figure this out?

Comment: Really I just wanted to use the priority inbox this way, so I had a look at the inspector to see if I could made it happen. The ^i meaning inbox was just an educated guess based on the other codes from that list.

Comment: Okay, a year later, I know, but this was stunningly impressive. Bravo.

Comment: Still working, this is unbelievable. I can't understand why the google engineers have not implemented this yet.

Comment: @Ben (or anyone else), is there any way to "OR" together multiple labels?  I've tried the following without any success: `^i,^u,(Work OR Home)` and `^i,^u,Work|Home`.

Comment: I am trying to follow  these instructions, and edit the 'inspect element' text in Chrome. I get as far as
Step 4 - I right click on the 'work' label and click 'inspect element'. I then search for 'cfg' and fine the one that is ^all,work and change the all to i. However, this doesn't seem to do anything? Do I have to save it some how? I can't seem to find a way to do this?

Comment: Amazing!  Note: `^u` doesn't include archived e-mail unless you also add `^all` to include archived mail. This is a perfect way to show IMAP mail from another account in a separate section of your priority inbox: `^u,^all,name@account.com`

Comment: @JamesM.Greene I was going to say you should start a new question for what you asked.  I did find a question that is *sort of* asking for what any "OR" operators might be though: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41029/how-can-i-customise-gmail-priority-inbox-to-show-multiple-labels-or-nested-labe ...but there

Comment: Brilliant!  No idea why they have to GUI to select a Label and specify Unread only, working with your trick though, thanks!

Comment: Used this again today to adjust my inboxes. Must find a way to give Ben more reputation for this answer; his discovery is too clever and too useful.

Comment: Is there a way to NOT a command? Like `-^t` or something to represent not starred?

Comment: As a heads up this method does not seem to work with Gmails new interface. You can perform the same exact steps but it does not seem to produce the same results. For example I have a Youtube video label, I selected that and edited it to be "^u,Youtube Subs". Doing that does filter by the label, but it includes unread AND read emails unfortunately. If anyone figures it out with the new interface I would love them forever

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "New Interface" definitely still works for me, but then I haven't noticed any interface change :) When you click the label does the priority inbox setting for that section read "Unread, Youtube Subs" or something else? It is obvious straight away if it works.

Comment: Still works like a charm in the "Classic interface"! However, new Gmail could not properly save such hacked settings. And this is the only thing stopping me to switch to the new one completely...

Comment: It seems pre-new interface custom inboxes remain, but now just show as empty. New ones can be added as per above, but again, just show as empty. Anyone have a solution since the recent gmail upgrades?

Comment: I think the new multiple inbox feature may be useful to do this kind of thing although not 100% coverage like the original solution. I have 3 extra inboxes with filters like in:inbox label:Work for my first section and in:inbox !label:Work is:unread for my second section and in:inbox !label:Work is:read for my 3rd section. The 4th inbox has everything but I am just ignoring that for now :(

Comment: @Ben thank you for pointing out the multiple inbox feature! It is VERY close to how we could do it in the old interface and enough for me, do you know if there is a way to hide the main inbox from view? As all of my custom inboxes include everything I need to be able to see at one time. Either way, thanks! You are awesome

Comment: Do you have a solution to the new interface?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently possible without a bit of hacking. (See [Ben's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7795/is-there-a-way-customize-priority-inbox-like-this/17646#17646).)

Out of the box you can have *Inbox and...*

- Important and unread
- Important
- Unread
- Starred

*OR* all of a particular label.

Can't combine Inbox and a different label the way you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Priority Inbox. When you select a label for a section, it automatically includes *all* of a particular label- both read an unread. I got around it by setting up two filters for items in the middle section. The rules for applying it are the same, but label names have (Unread) or (Archived) after it. Select the one with the unread qualifier for your section. When the message comes in, both labels are applied and it is filtered into the proper section in priority inbox. After I read it, I remove the (unread) label and leave the (archived) label. It is automatically removed from the priority inbox screen, but I can easily find it later.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [Ben](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/10322/ben)'s [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17646/252882) no longer works.  I've done some investigation into making this possible again, but don't have a full answer yet.

In the settings, choose Priority Inbox, and click Save Settings.  You can see the network request it makes request under the [in the developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network).  In the request payload, the settings for priority inbox are under `1.1.0.1.2.88147817.181538083.7.2`.  It will be a list of four items for the four inbox sections.

The `1` property of these items is the type of the section.  The available types are:

```
 7 = ...
 8 = Important
 9 = Unread
10 = Important and Unread
11 = Starred
12 = ...
13 = All Important
14 = All Starred
15 = All Drafts
16 = All Sent
```

Types `7` and `12` are special.  `7` represents "everything else", but it is removed from the list unless it is at the end.  `12` looks at the value in property `2` to determine what it does, and the values for property `2` can be the values in Ben's original answer!

My goal in this investigation was to allow me put the "everything else" section in the middle, and I was able to accomplish that by using `^i` in property `2`.

This is not, however, a full solution to the original question since the `2` property does not seem to allow commas.  Hopefully this can be of use to someone, though.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> In inbox type choose "Multiple Inboxes"
Here you can make your own 5 search queries.

Queries that I have found:

`is:unread` - filtered unread emails
`is:read` - filtered read emails
`is:starred` - filtered starred emails
`in:archive` - filtered archived emails
`is:drafts` - filtered drafts
`label:my-label` - filtered specific label emails
`-label:my-label` - (added minus before) those labels won't be filtered

Query version: specific label and in the inbox:
`label:my-label in:inbox`

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do this.

1. Go to **Settings > Priority Inbox**
2. You'll see four **Priority Inbox Sections**
3. Click on **Add section** beside the **Empty** section (usually the third one)
4. A menu will open and you can select the label you want, and your section will be about all *Inbox items that have a particular label*.

You'll later be able to choose how many items you'd like to display in your section.

I guess that's exactly what you want. I've tried it myself and it works.

Comment: No, this does not work. It shows **all** emails with [label] and not only the emails that are also in Inbox.

Comment: Sorry for that. I thought because "more options..." is in the part with "In Inbox and" that it works the same with labels so like "In Inbox and labelled [label]". It showed correctly with the label I used, because first 10 items were all in Inbox. Stupid of me.