# Equivalent of 'archive' for priority inbox \ multiple inbox

Tags: gmail

I'm using multiple inbox to split between my general mail and work related mail (which has a specific label)

To avoid seeing the work mail also in the inbox section, I archive the mail labeled work.

But in this situation, there is no way to 'archive' the work mail from the work inbox. currently I use stars to mark mail that should be seen in the work inbox (and use the filter is:starred and label:work for the section)

priority inbox is even more problematic, as you can filter just by label, and not use a complex query.

Does any one have a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the Priority Inbox although not with functionality out of the box.

The only way that I have found to do it is either with the element inspector in chrome/safari or with firebug in firefox. The good news is that once you have made the settings change it will work in all browsers.

1. Go to the priority inbox settings tab.
2. Click the options next to the
   section you want to show your work
   mail.
3. Click "More Options..."
4. Inspect the element for the "Work" Label
5. You will notice on the surrounding
   div there is an attribute
   cfg="^all,Work", change the value to "^i,Work"
6. Select the label on the page as you normally would

You will know if it worked or not straight away because the section settings should now read : Inbox, Work instead of the All Work that it used to read.

You now have your mail split and can still Archive Work labelled mail to remove it from the inbox.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. is there a similar way to hide the work mails from the regular inbox? (have the filter of the main section be `label:inbox -label:work`

Comment: Priority Inbox will automatically filter them out of the "Everything Else" section. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Works!. the only remaining (small) issue is that the work section needs to be before the inbox

Comment: You can make it the first section in your priority inbox (above important) by going to the priority inbox settings and making it the first one.

Comment: I can't get this to work - can anyone provide more information on how to inspect the element and save changes? Thanks

Comment: @Ben, can you add some pics please, so that other viewers (less experienced) can figure out what to do, more precisely? Thanks !!

Comment: Indeed, as user37056 remarked above, I have also not been able to save the changes. We make the changes in the attribute, then the label in the dropdown menu changes, so we select it, then we save the changes at the bottom of the page which takes us back to the inbox. But once there, the label is back to 'all, label' emails and not the desired one 'inbox, label'. How do we save the changes?

Comment: Of course, I am right now using a stupid solution for this. I have simply created another filter, by adding the 'label:inbox AND' to my desired label. This solves the issue but it is a round about solution. Am not happy with it.

Comment: @Shripad some people over at the other question have mentioned this method no longer works on the new gmail interface. Maybe that is your issue? I still use this method to segregate my inbox in the classic interface and confirm it was still working when I made to changes last week. The method is exactly the same as in Sonja's pictures from below. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @ Ben, indeed. You are right. I went to the earlier version and checked. It works. But when I come back to the newer version, that particular part of the inbox disappears.

Answer (score 4):

This has totally changed my life, thanks. My inbox is about four hundred times more useful now.

I am a total n00b, but I thought I would add some images, because I have found this procedure so helpful. I hope they make sense.

In my case, I wanted to have a section in my inbox for uni emails that weren't yet archived.

1. Go to settings

[image: gmail settings]

2. Go to the Inbox tab in settings (ignore the fact that my section is already called 'Inbox, uni' here – I had already renamed it)

   [image: gmail settings inbox tab]
3. Click on 'options' and then 'more options'

[image]

4. Scroll down to the label you want to modify (in my case, 'uni'), and right-click on it.

   [image]
5. This will bring up the menu. Go down to 'inspect element'

[image]

6. Have a look at the surrounding div, and you will see cfg="^all,uni" (or the equivalent)
   [image]
7. Click on the element (i.e. literally click on the word all), and type in 'i' instead of 'all'

[image]

8. Save changes! That's it.

Now, when you go back to your inbox, your section should be there. Try archiving a couple of messages and see if they disappear from your inbox.

Comment: Thank you Sonja. I am not able to save the changes. Is there a menu which will allow me to save the changes? On the dropdown menu for the priority inbox, it does change the label name to 'Inbox, uni' but once I go back to the inbox (after saving the changes) it is back to the 'all, uni'. I am using a less intelligent method for this. I have simply created a filter for 'label:inbox AND label:uni' and then use this label in the priority inbox. But more information on saving the changes would be useful.

Comment: As Ben pointed out above, your method works perfectly well with the earlier version of Gmail, not with the recent version though. We will have to wait for Gmail to improve.