# How can I customise Gmail Priority Inbox to show multiple labels (or nested labels) in one section?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, priority-inbox

I have nested labels (Work, Work/Brighton, Work/London). When I select the parent label "Work" for a section, the children "Work/Brighton" and "Work/London" are not automatically added to that section (emails need to have both labels to be added to that section, example: Work, Work/Brighton or Work, Work/London).

Is there a way of having a child label added to the section decided by its parent label? (This should be the whole point of inheritance)

Another take on this would be having multiple labels in one section. Following [Ben](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/10322/ben)'s hacking answer at 
[Gmail Priority Inbox showing non archived labels in a section](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17646/35409), I tried doing ^i,Work,Work/Brighton,Work/London but it does not work. The comma (,) is used as an AND operator here, is there anyone who knows the OR operator for this?

Cheers Dylan

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, have you tried the Multiple Inboxes lab feature?

Click the gear icon -> *Settings* -> *Labs*, and find Multiple Inboxes.
When you have activated it, a new tab appears on the settings screen.

It lets you divide your inbox view into multiple sections. Each section displays the results of a pre-defined search.

It should be possible to specify a search that includes your label and its sub-labels, but you would have to update the search term if you add new sub-labels.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I got around it by applying the same label again. So in your case you make a filter for Work/Brighton and apply it to the Brighton emails, and then make another filter for Work and apply it to the Brighton emails. Stupid, I know, but it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it... You need to create duplicate filter for your e-mail. Like in the above example, they need to have one filter setup to go to "work" and the other setup to go to "Brighton". It's not the best fix, but I got it to work.

Hope this helps!