# Gmail Inbox, show all threads with a label in default Inbox view

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-labels

I want 4 fields in my default view in gmail:

- important
- label "to read"
- label "to do"
- everything else

I am almost there, but the "to do" and "to read" fields do not show threads which have the label but are also in Inbox. I want the fields to show all conversations with the appropriate label.

I read this "[Is there a way customize priority inbox like this?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7795/is-there-a-way-customize-priority-inbox-like-this)" but it doesn't seem to work (anymore).

Comment: Can you clarify or post a screenshot of what your default view looks like and describe what's missing? E.g. "default view" can mean multiple things. It could be that those are the labels that you have showing in the upper-left to choose from. Another is that you could have [multiple inboxes](http://lifehacker.com/5147677/gmail-labs-adds-multiple-inboxes) with each field. Or, maybe you mean something else.

Comment: It's the priority inbox. By default it has "Important" and "Everything else". I disabled other tabs in Options->Configure inbox. In Options->Settings->Inbox I selected Piority Inbox, and added the sections "To read" and "To do".