# How to hide archived emails in Gmail Priority Inbox?

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

I am using Gmail's Priority Inbox and I have created custom sections based on labels to organize my work email.

When I archive an email in my 'Important and unread' or 'Everything else' sections, they disappear from the section. This is what I want.

However, with my custom sections that are based on labels, emails remain shown, even though it has been archived.

Is there a way to hide archived emails from my custom sections?

Comment: This is actually possible: See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17646/134091

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you can. When configuring a custom section for Priority Inbox, your option for messages is either:

Inbox and one of (Important and Unread, Important, Unread, Starred)

***OR***

All from one particular label.

You can't define a search (`label:my-label is:unread` for instance) for a priority inbox section.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is quite old. But it comes up quite high in the search results when looking to solve this.

In the 2019 version of Gmail, you can click the 3-dots menu on the right side of the Archived label. Under **In message list**, select **Hide**. That will omit those messages from the Priority inbox.

Comment: Looks like the **Archived** label recently disappeared from the labels list. Archived messages can now be accessed from the **All mail** view, which seems to be the only way.
Your solution seems therefore not applicable anymore.

Comment: I've been looking for a while for a solution. This one does it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same situation and here my solution:

add - `is:inbox` - that will select messages in inbox (not archived)

Here some extraversion that I have found:

`is:unread` - filtered unread emails
`is:read` - filtered read emails
`is:starred` - filtered starred emails
`in:archive` - filtered archived emails
`-label:my-label` - (added minus before) those labels won't be filtered

Filter version: specific label and in the inbox:
`label:my-label in:inbox`