# How do I setup Gmail priority labels with intricate filters?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, priority-inbox

I have a filter for important, unread and starred. Every time I try to change my Gmail priority inbox to the that label, it changes to: "All Everything Else." It doesn't matter if I try inbox #1, 2 or 3.

Here's the label: "label:starred-important-and-unread" I made the filter by putting that string into the "Has words" section of the filter creation box.

Here are some screenshots

The filter

[image: filter]

The inbox:

[image: inbox]

What happens when I press save:

[image: result]

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried putting you label as, say, the third section of the Inbox? In my quick tests it doesn't seem to like having anything but one of the general Priority Inbox options in the first slot.

Comment: This _might_ be helpful: [Is there a way customize priority inbox like this?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7795/354)

Answer (score 1):

Remove all spaces and commas from the label name and try again. That worked for me.

```
Doesn't work: "Is Starred, Important, Unread"
Works: "Is_Starred_Important_Unread".
```

You can then rename the label and it will still work . . . but if you go back to Settings/Inbox and hit "save changes" then any labels that have spaces or commas in them will revert back to "All Everything Else".